# Asian-language characters being messed up through transfer

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

OK, I have a web app that uses PHP, MySQL and JavaScript. In an input box, you type something and if the user types in words using Korean/Chinese/Japanese then it will be messed up.

It appears like this: `ãƒ˜ãƒ“ãƒ¼ãƒ­ãƒ¼ãƒ†ãƒ¼ã‚·ãƒ§ãƒ³`.

It uses a AJAX call and passes through JavaScript wrapped around in `encodeURIComponent()`, so maybe that's it? I don't know. In the MySQL database it shows messed up, too!

My charset encoding on my webpage is `iso-8859-1`. Help?

Comment: do you have tried UTF-8.If this not help you embedded the font through font-face in css3 if you use custom fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My charset encoding on my webpage is iso-8859-1

That won't work. You need to upgrade to UTF-8 for non-European languages.

Comment: That's what I thought was the problem. So I just change it to `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`?

Comment: Your PHP and database also need to be made unicode-compatible. PHP should be easy, but your existing database will probably need to be converted.

Comment: In `General Settings` of my MySQL phpmyadmin, my `MySQL connection collation ` is `utf8_general_ci` .. is that right?